# Documenting a COM Object for Intellisense/Object Browser, etc

Tags: c++, .net, com, documentation, intellisense

A C++ (native) application I'm working on uses a COM interface for its modules.

In the .odl file there are tonnes of documentation providing information outlining the function/parameters, etc..

Between the typelib generation, and subsequent tlbimp.exe importation; the interop assembly I get back to use in .NET includes only the function/interface names and a list of their parameters and types.

I'm wondering if there is any way (format documentation in a specific way / third party applications / parameters for tlbimp.exe / ???) that I could transfer this documentation across so that it appears in the Visual Studio object browser, or even better, the .NET intellisense.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You author auto-completion help for a COM automation component with the [helpstring] attribute in the IDL file.  Unfortunately Tlbimp.exe does not support that, there is no mechanism in .NET to embed help text inside an assembly.  .NET IntelliSense use .xml files, they are normally auto-generated from the source code with the /doc compiler option.  They are much easier to localize.

While it sounds feasible to auto-generate the .xml file from the type library, I don't know anybody that has tackled this yet.  A starting point would be the managed tlbimp project [located here](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/17579).

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer- despite my optimistic holding out that someone would come-in and say it was possible; thanks for pointing me in the right direction!